# Bridging between incompatible types in Swift using memory rebind

Tags: objective-c, arrays, swift, memory-management, casting

I have been trying to solve a problem in my app. I get an NSArray from an Objective-C API and need to read it as an array of double values in the Swift app. 
So the bridging needed is between NSArray in Objective-C and a Double Array in Swift.

`NSArray ----> Double array`

I don't want to typecast the array using `as [Double]` since this array is huge and thus the process of typecasting is time consuming. 

 
The array needs to be consumed using Accelerate framework functions, so just need to rebind the memory to `Double`. 

 
I have tried rebinding the memory to Double but the application behaves unexpectedly. I am not sure if this is because bridging can only happen between compatible types.

What is the right way to bridge two incompatible types in an optimized way? 
Is it even possible or O(N) is the only way?

Comment: That *cannot* work, memory rebinding is possible only between layout *compatible* types.

Comment: The answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43381897/how-to-cast-element-from-unsafemutablepointeruint8-in-swift-to-uint8-in-c?s=11|54.8139 may help